# Insert query results in "Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

After the submit button is clicked, a record is not stored. All syntax I have look through, all look fine. Where is the thing stopping it to insert? Most of the guidance I look through almost is because select statement, but now I'm insert statement and same issue occur.

Here's my code:

```
<table border='1'>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">
                    <h1>Property For Rent</h1>
                </th>
            <form method="post">
                <tr><td>Property NO:</td><td><input type="textbox" name="pid"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Street:</td><td><input type="textbox" name="street"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>City:</td><td><input type="textbox" name="city"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Post Code:</td><td><input type="textbox" name="postcode"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Type:</td><td><input type="textbox" name="type"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Rooms:</td><td><input type="textbox" name="rooms"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Rent:</td><td><input type="textbox" name="rent"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Owner No:</td><td><select name="ownerno">
                            <?php 
                                $conon=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','dreamhome');
                                $SQLon="select distinct ownerNo from propertyforrent";
                                $queryresulton = mysqli_query($conon,$SQLon);
                                while($resulton=mysqli_fetch_array($queryresulton))
                                {
                                    echo '<option value=" '.$resulton['ownerNo'].' ">'.$resulton['ownerNo'].'</option>';
                                }
                                ?>
                            </td></tr>
                <tr><td>Staff No:</td><td><select name="staffno">
                            <?php 
                                $consn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','dreamhome');
                                $SQLsn="select distinct staffNo from propertyforrent";
                                $queryresultsn = mysqli_query($consn,$SQLsn);
                                while($resultsn=mysqli_fetch_array($queryresultsn))
                                {
                                    echo '<option value=" '.$resultsn['staffNo'].' ">'.$resultsn['staffNo'].'</option>';
                                }
                                ?>
                            </td></tr>
                <tr><td>Branch No:</td><td><select name="branchno">
                            <?php 
                                $conbn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','dreamhome');
                                $SQLbn="select distinct branchNo from propertyforrent";
                                $queryresultbn = mysqli_query($conbn,$SQLbn);
                                while($resultbn=mysqli_fetch_array($queryresultbn))
                                {
                                    echo '<option value=" '.$resultbn['branchNo'].' ">'.$resultbn['branchNo'].'</option>';
                                }
                                ?>
                            </td></tr>
                <td><input type="Submit" name="submit">

                            </td>
            </form>
        </table>
                    <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                    {
                        if((!empty($_POST['pid']))&&(!empty($_POST['street']))&&(!empty($_POST['city']))
                        &&(!empty($_POST['postcode']))&&(!empty($_POST['type']))&&(!empty($_POST['rooms']))&&(!empty($_POST['rent']))
                        &&(!empty($_POST['ownerno']))&&(!empty($_POST['staffno']))&&(!empty($_POST['branchno'])))
                        {
                            $conad=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','dreamhome');
                            if(!$conad)
                            {
                                    echo 'Note connected to server';
                            } 

                            if(!mysqli_select_db($conad,'dreamhome'))
                            {
                                echo 'Database Not Selected';
                            }

                            $pid=mysqli_real_escape_string($conad,$_POST['pid']);
                            $street=mysqli_real_escape_string($conad,$_POST['street']);
                            $city=mysqli_real_escape_string($conad,$_POST['city']);
                            $postcode=mysqli_real_escape_string($conad,$_POST['postcode']);
                            $type=mysqli_real_escape_string($conad,$_POST['type']);
                            $rooms=mysqli_real_escape_string($conad,$_POST['rooms']);
                            $rent=mysqli_real_escape_string($conad,$_POST['rent']);
                            $ownerno=mysqli_real_escape_string($conad,$_POST['ownerno']);
                            $staffno=mysqli_real_escape_string($conad,$_POST['staffno']);
                            $branchno=mysqli_real_escape_string($conad,$_POST['branchno']);

                            $SQLad= "INSERT INTO propertyforrent (propertyNo,street,city,postcode,type,rooms,rent,ownerNo,staffNo,branchNo)
                                    VALUES ('$pid','$street','$city','$postcode','$type','$rooms','$rent','$ownerno','$staffno','$branchno')";
                            $resultad=mysqli_query($conad,$SQLad);

                            if(!$resultad)
                            {
                                echo "record not save!,mysqli_error($conad)"; **<-- here the error mentioned occur**
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                echo "record save!";
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "<h1>Please fill up all field!</h1>";
                        }


                    }
                    ?>
```

The error prompted out from mysqli_error is

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted
>   to string in

I am just a beginner in PHP and HTML, I started two months ago.

Comment: On __which__ line?

Comment: Why do you keep opening a new connection before each query?

Comment: When a query returns `false` you should call `mysqli_error()` to get the error message and display that so you know why it failed.

Comment: The error message means that you're using one of the `$conxx` variables in a place where a string is needed. I don't see where this might be happening, but the error message should have a line number telling you where it is.

Comment: You should also learn to use prepared statements instead of substituting variables into SQL strings.

Comment: @Barmar because if i'm doing with [include("con_db.php"); ], it doesn't work at all, i hope i can do it too. but still can't i figure it out..

Comment: If you don't tell us which line the error happens on, it's hard to help you.

Comment: @Barmar mentioned above aldy... thanks

Comment: I don't see any way that `echo "record not save!,mysqli_error($SQLad)";` could cause that error. Note that it's not even calling the function because it's inside quotes. `$SQLad` is a string, not a `mysqli` object.

Comment: @u_mulder mentioned above aldy.. in the coding aldy... thanks

Comment: That error would happen if you wrote `echo "record not save!,mysqli_error($conad)";`

Comment: What you should write is `echo "record not save! " . mysqli_error($conad);`

Comment: @Barmar I presume it is "already"

Comment: @u_mulder he has it marked with `**<-- here the error mentioned occur**`

Comment: @Barmar oopps... i was running with  mysqli_error($conad), not the top one. then the error come out... btw, would you think is that because of the <select> element within the table causing the problem, cause i feel like there's no value retrieved after i've chosen the option.. do you think so?

Comment: yeappp... you both just learn a malaysian-slang-english word lol..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling `mysqli_error()` correctly to show the error message. Inside double-quoted strings variables are replaced, but functions are not called. So when you write:

```
echo "record not save!,mysqli_error($conad)";
```

it tries to replace the variable `$conad` with its value. But this can only be done when the value is a string or number, you can't put a MySQLI connection in a string.

You need to call the function outside the string and concatenate it.

```
echo "record not save! " . mysqli_error($conad);
```

or give multiple arguments to `echo`:

```
echo "record not save! ", mysqli_error($conad);
```

The reason your `INSERT` query isn't working is because you have extra spaces in the `value` attributes in your options.

```
echo '<option value=" '.$resulton['ownerNo'].' ">'.$resulton['ownerNo'].'</option>';
```

has a space after the `"` character, so it's creating

```
<option value=" CO40 ">
```

instead of

```
<option value="CO40">
```

Change it to:

```
echo '<option value="'.$resulton['ownerNo'].'">'.$resulton['ownerNo'].'</option>';
```

and similarly for all the other lines that create options.

Comment: i do... there's a [,] (comma) sign there.. isn't it work similarly as (.) too?

Comment: The comma is inside the string, it needs to be outside the string.

Comment: but anyway.. it just show what's wrong with my code. now my concern how could i solve it.. lol... 3 hours just stuck in this line is not fun man... crying...

Comment: alright, i have changed to what you told. Similarly, the record is not inserted too. but ironically, a new error message is presented, something like "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dreamhome`.`propertyforrent`, CONSTRAINT `propertyforrent_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ownerNo`) REFERENCES `privateowner` (`ownerNo`))" hmmm... i feel like it's because of the database issue aldy right?

Comment: Your `propertyforrent.ownerNo` column is a foreign key. Have to add the `ownerNo` to the `privateowner` table before you can use it in `propertyforrent`.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're getting an incorrect `$ownerno`, since the menu comes from existing owners. Try `echo $SQLad;` to see what's actually in the query.

Comment: yeah... is it meaning the new row I insert, the ownerNo is not in my privateowner table right? Then, is that because of the form <select> <option> elements issue? It does retrieve the value of ownerNo by query, i think it must be I'm failed to tell the compiler what to value to take, when the user has chosen this option. Eg, user choose "PG08" option, but the system capture nothing because of I didn't specify the "PG08" option is PG08 value in the table. am i right in describing these thing?

Comment: Here's what coming out after echo '$SQLad;' INSERT INTO propertyforrent (propertyNo,street,city,postcode,type,rooms,rent,ownerNo,staffNo,branchNo) VALUES ('MY01','jalan besar','seremban','11122j','flat','2','658',' CO40 ',' SG14 ',' B002 ')

Comment: `echo '<option value=" '.$resulton['ownerNo'].' ">'.$resulton['ownerNo'].'</option>';` looks correct to me. Also, you test `!empty($_POST['ownerno'])`.

Comment: but the 'CO40', 'SG14', 'B002' .. all is valid value from the (initial) table. It just doesn't added into the propertyforrent table.

Comment: You have extra spaces around the values. See the updated answer.

Comment: yeah... i also realize that when echo the SQL statement, that 3 foreign key, ('CO40', 'SG14', 'B002'). Have a space in front and behind. will it be the root caused of all the issue? Since I declare the data type as varchar in database, i guess the system might treated 'CO40' and ' CO40 ' differently..

Comment: exactly... i found out it too.. any way to omit the space out?

Comment: Thanks man!!! love you so much!!! I think the problem remaining there is because of I didn't refresh it.. lol... thanks anyway... -by aldy..